# Getting the median value from the database

Tags: sql, oracle, select

A median is defined as a number separating the higher half of a data set from the lower half. Query the median of the Northern Latitudes (LAT_N) from STATION and round your answer to  decimal places.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

```
Field : Type
ID    : NUMBER
CITY  : VARCHAR2(21)
STATE : VARCHAR2(2)
LAT_N : NUMBER
LONG_W: NUMBER
```

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

I could only manage to get the row index for the median value with

```
select floor((count(lat_n)+1)/2) from station;
```

which is row index 250. The  next step is to use this value to extract out the lat_n value at row index 250. How do I transform to SQL?

Comment: Which database system? Oracle?SQLS? Postgres? Mysql? etc

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a near guarantee that this has been asked before, do please have a search (using google to search this site if necesasary - its' better than SO's built in search) and let us know what you've tried

Comment: Tagged with `oracle` based on the usage of the `number` and `varchar2` data types

Comment: Edge case: For even-numbered tables, the median is usually reported as the _mean_ value of the middle two records.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you've dumped the text in from a homework or examwork type exercise, and I don't submit answers for those by default because I don't regard using SO as a homework completion device to be a sensible use of time with regards to your own learning. Do please take a look at https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/median.php though - oracle has a function to do median, and your question as is lacks sufficient detail for anyone other than you (who knows what you want the median per) to complete..

Comment: @CaiusJard I didn't know Oracle has a built in median function.  Maybe I should not have answered.

Comment: Well, the good thing about your answer is it'll work in 9i, and it's a better learning tool than using the builtin :)

Answer (score 6):

**For mySQL** This will work,

```
   SELECT ROUND(S1.LAT_N, 4) 
    FROM STATION AS S1 
    WHERE (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(S1.ID)/2) - 1 
           FROM STATION) = 
          (SELECT COUNT(S2.ID) 
           FROM STATION AS S2 
           WHERE S2.LAT_N > S1.LAT_N);
```

refrence : https://nikkesan.gitbook.io/hackerrank/practice-1/sql/aggregation/untitled-2

Answer (score 6):

You can run the following code using Oracle.

```
SELECT ROUND(MEDIAN(LAT_N), 4)
FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to use the [`median()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions086.htm) function:

```
select median(lat_n)
from stations;
```

You can round the value using functions such as `round()` or `to_char()`.

Comment: This function is only available in Oracle.

Comment: @Wiebke . . . The question is tagged Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

*SQL SERVER:*

```
DECLARE @slno int;
SET @slno= (select COUNT(*) from STATION);
with cte (ind,LAT_N)
as
( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LAT_N ASC) AS ind, LAT_N from STATION
)
select 
CAST(LAT_N AS DECIMAL(15,4))
from cte
where ind= (@slno+1)/2
order by LAT_N
```

1. In cte - add row number to each row and name the column as ind.
2. In variable slno - add the total number of rows
3. print Lat_N where the index calculated in step 1 falls in the middle such that the middle position will be slno+1/2 calculated in step 2.

Comment: Please brief your answer - how this solves the question. Thanks.

Comment: step1: In cte --add row number to each row and name the column as ind.
step2: In variable slno - add the total number of rows
step 3: print Lat_N where the index calculated in step 1 falls in the middle such that the middle position will be slno+1/2 calculated in step 2.

Answer (score 2):

**Easy explanation of the sample median:**
In individual series (if number of observation is very low) first one must arrange all the observations in order. 
Then **count(n)** is the total number of observation in given data.

If n is **odd** then Median (M) = value of ((n + 1)/2)th item term.

If n is **even** then Median (M) = value of [(n/2)th item term + (n/2 + 1)th item term]/2

[CTE in Sql Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)

Query:

```
declare @cont int,@reccount int,@first int, @second int;
set @reccount=(select COUNT(id) from STATION);
IF @reccount%2=0 --even rows
set @cont=(((@reccount)/2)+(((@reccount)/2)+1))/2; 
ELSE 
set @cont=((select count(id) from station)+1)/2;
--creating CTE
WITH Station_CTE (rowNum, Lat_n)
AS (
select row_number() over(order by lat_n desc) as 'rowNum',lat_n from station
)
SELECT top(1) SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(30),ROUND((scte.lat_n),4)),1,(CHARINDEX('.',ROUND((scte.lat_n),4),1)+4)) from Station s inner join Station_CTE as scte on scte.rowNum =@cont
```

Expected Output:

```
83.8913
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select round(lat_n,4) from
(select lat_n, rank() over(order by lat_n) as rank1 
from station) dummyTable
where rank1 = 
(select 
case 
when mod(count(*),2) = 0 then round(count(*)/2)
else round((count(*)+1)/2)
end as rank1
from station s2)
```

1. Creating a dummy table with "lat_n" ordered ascendingly
2. Using the windows function "rank() over()" to give row number for each record
3. Then filtering for the median row using the rank and retrieving the 'lat_n' value for that row

Hope this helped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for mysql:

```
SET @table_size := (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM STATION);

SELECT ROUND(AVG(LAT_N), 4)
FROM (select LAT_N, row_number() over (order by LAT_N) as RN from STATION) temp
WHERE (
    CASE WHEN (@table_size % 2 = 0)
        THEN
            RN IN (ROUND(@table_size / 2, 0), ROUND(@table_size / 2, 0) + 1)
        ELSE
            RN = ROUND(@table_size / 2, 0)
    END
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option.  We can assign a row number, while at the same time computing the total table count.  Then, for tables with an even number of records, we can take the average of the middle two records as the median.  For odd numbered tables, we can just take the middle record.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT s.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY lat_n) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    FROM station s
)

SELECT AVG(lat_n)
FROM cte
WHERE
    (MOD(cnt, 2) = 0 AND rn IN (FLOOR(cnt/2), FLOOR(cnt/2) + 1)) OR
    (MOD(cnt, 2) = 1 AND rn = FLOOR(cnt/2) + 1);
```

### Demo

Note: For tables with an even number of records, it should be obvious that there is no exact median/middle record.  But many statisticians just report the average of the middle pair of records in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Position int
set @position = round((select count(LAT_N)/2 from STATION),0)

select convert(decimal(20,4),LAT_N) from STATION
order by LAT_N
offset @position rows
fetch next 1 row only
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work with mySQL:

- Sort the values from column `lat_n`
- Index to each row.
- If the count of the values in the column is odd, find the value of the item in the middle of the sorted list. Or if is is even, find the values of the two items in the middle of the sorted list, calculate the average and return it.

`SET @rowindex := -1;`

```
SELECT
   round(AVG(lat_n),4)
FROM
   (SELECT @rowindex:=@rowindex + 1 AS rowindex, lat_n
    FROM station
    ORDER BY lat_n) 
    AS g
WHERE
g.rowindex IN (FLOOR(@rowindex / 2) , CEIL(@rowindex / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL :**

```
select round(s.lat_n,4) from station s where (select round(count(id)/2)-1 from station) = (select count(s1.id) from station s1 where s1.lat_n > s.lat_n);
```

Two sub-queries will be equated when subquery-1 i.e, index count  of half of the rows in the table,and sub query 2 which returns the number of s1.lat_n that are greater than the corresponding s.lat_n .

Answer (score 1):

with cte
as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY LAT_N)rw,LAT_N FROM STATION
group by LAT_N
    )

```
select cast(lat_n as decimal(10,4)) from cte
where rw=
(select (count(rw)/2 )+1 from cte)
```

Comment: Give some context to your answer. What does it do compared to other solutions? What does it add to the stack?

Answer (score 1):

> Try This Solution

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(LAT_N), 4) AS median_lat_n
FROM (
    SELECT t1.LAT_N
    FROM (
        SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS `row_number`, s.LAT_N
        FROM STATION s, (SELECT @row_num:=0) t
        WHERE s.LAT_N IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY s.LAT_N
    ) t1,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows
        FROM STATION
    ) t2
    WHERE t1.`row_number` IN ((t2.total_rows+1)/2, (t2.total_rows+2)/2)
) t3;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work
Oracle:

```
SELECT round(median(lat_n),4) from station;
```

Comment: This is a good answer that addresses the poster's main point, but I'm not sure the rounding is necessary. Perhaps just `select median(lat_n) from station;`

Comment: I guess the answer is related to HackerRanks's challenge where it was asked to round the result to 4decimal place @catfood

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL code :

```
SELECT ROUND(lat_n,4)
---------------------
FROM (
     SELECT lat_n,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY lat_n ) AS row_num
     FROM station
     )  AS new_table
--------------------
WHERE row_num = (
                SELECT CEIL(AVG(row_num)) 
                FROM (
                      SELECT 
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY lat_n ) AS row_num
                      FROM station
                      )  AS new_table
                 )
-------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

We all know what the median is when the number of elements is odd and even it is the (n+1)/2th term when odd and ((n/2)th term + (n/2)+1th term)/2 so use this code.

```
set @r1=0,@r2=0,@r3=0,@r4=0;
select
case
when mod(count(cnt),2)=0 then 
                        ((select round(lat_n,4) from (select @r3:=@r3+1 as cnt2, lat_n from station order by lat_n) temp2 where cnt2=(@r3)/2)+(select round(lat_n,4) from (select @r4:=@r4+1 as cnt3, lat_n from station order by lat_n) temp3 where cnt3=(@r4+1)/2))/2
else (select round(lat_n,4) from (select @r2:=@r2+1 as cnt1, lat_n from station order by lat_n) temp1 where cnt1=(@r2+1)/2)
end
from (select @r1:=@r1+1 as cnt, lat_n from station ) temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Code :

```
SELECT ROUND (LAT_N,4)

FROM ( SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N DESC) AS ROWNUMBER, LAT_N FROM STATION ) 
AS LAT_N

WHERE ROWNUMBER = ( SELECT ((COUNT(LAT_N) + 1) /2) 
       FROM STATION)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as MS SQL Server solution:

```
select format(round(b.lat_n, 4), ".####")
from station a
join (select id, lat_n, row_number()over(order by lat_n) as rn
from station) b
on a.id = b.id
where b.rn = (select floor((count(lat_n)+1)/2) from station)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that is more robust than hardcoding the '+1' and more efficient than including an 'IF' statement.

WITH Tbl AS(
select row_number() over (order by lat_n) rc, lat_n
from station)

Select cast(avg(lat_n) as Decimal(15,4))
from tbl
where rc = (select ceiling(max(rc)/2.0) from tbl)

Answer (score 1):

If using MS SQL (for reference, although question tagged with Oracle):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LAT_N) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY null) 
    AS DECIMAL(10,4)
) AS Median
FROM STATION;
```

MS SQL does not have function to find median, but it has PERCENTILE_CONT() to find the percentile based on the distribution. Use "PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5)" to get the median value; "PARTITION BY null" as this question needs no specific partition; and use "DISTINCT" to retrieve single result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @r = 0;

SELECT ROUND(AVG(Lat_N), 4)
FROM (SELECT (@r := @r + 1) AS r, Lat_N FROM Station ORDER BY Lat_N) Temp
WHERE
    r = (SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / 2) FROM Station) OR
    r = (SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / 2) + 1) FROM Station)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with using MySQL

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT ROUND(lat_n,4)
FROM (

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, lat_n, (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(*)/2) FROM station) AS count_of
FROM
    station
    ORDER BY lat_n ASC
) AS new_table
WHERE num = count_of
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using MS SQL Server**

```
    with ST as(
    select rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N),LAT_N from Station
)
select cast(LAT_N as decimal (10,4)) from ST Where rn=(select (Count(rn)/2)+1 from ST);
```