# how to do ceil for count of the records and use this number as offset in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, median

am new t sql and am trying to solve this Question:
[Getting the median value from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291508/getting-the-median-value-from-the-database)

I am trying initially to order the table by `LAT_N` and then doing offset with the value of the middle, the value of the middle will be the ceil of the number of records divided by two.
so for this I tried:

```
select round(LAT_N,4)
from STATION
order by LAT_N desc
limit 1
offset ceil ((select count(LAT_N) from STATION)/2)
```

but am getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near '((select count(LAT_N) from STATION)/2)' at
> line 6

I am wondering how to retrieve the ceil as a number to use it for offset? what did I do wrong?

Comment: Please tell us what database do you use ? Oracle ? MySQL? Maybe SQLServer ? I see that it is MySQL  from the error ? Why not adding the tag in your question ?

Comment: Does MySQL support an arbitrary expression as `offset` argument?

Comment: From MySQL 8 you can use the method shown at the URL where you use row_number  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291658/2067753  to calculate the midpoint

Comment: thanks all for your comments @VBoka yea it's mysql

Comment: @jarlh yea it works fine when I hard code the number"

Comment: @PaulMaxwell yea I saw the answer but I need to understand what's wrong with my approach

Comment: Use a variable to hold the offset value, you can't run a subquery at that location I believe that is why

Comment: add to above: I think you need to use dynamic sql to implement that calculated number as the offset.

Comment: To be clear: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` accept only positive integer literals, or parameter placeholders, or local variables in a stored routine. You can't use an expression or a user-defined variable. The documentation that covers this is in [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) (search for "The LIMIT clause...").

Answer (score 0):

ciel() isn't a MySQL function and it isn't possible to use a subquery as the offset number (sadly)

You need (it seems) to use dynamic sql to get this to work, e.g.

```
SET @table_name:='information_schema.columns';

set @offset := (select cast(count(*)/2 as unsigned) from information_schema.columns);

SET @sql:=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@table_name, ' order by column_name limit 1 offset ',@offset);

select @sql;

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

note you can place the /2 and cast the value to an unsigned integer inside that subquery to calculate the midpoint.

see a working *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9b1de96babd23b3c4a4abf1b72a39a9)*